# Restaurant in Paris decorated in kitchen utensils

Tags: paris, identify-this, restaurants

What is the name of the restaurant decorated with kitchen utensils, in Paris nearby Porte Maillot and Le Palais des Congrès de Paris?

Comment: Can you include a photo by chance?

Comment: @Flimzy, photos here, it looks like the Nikita has nailed it. Great FGITW too.  http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/chez-cl%C3%A9ment-paris-23?select=HrKHFKGLKEYKlpvbYZTy0Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably Chez Clément ! This restaurant has a lot of pots hung on the ceiling by the entrance.

Comment: +1,  123 avenue Champs Elysées, 75008 Paris,

Comment: Lots of them inside, too. Look up!

Comment: Please note that Chez Clément is a chain with multiple restaurants inside and outside Paris. One of them is at Porte Maillot, and another one is on the Champs Elysées. http://www.chezclement.com/